# Qt- is there a way to preferentially resize child widgets

Tags: c++, qt, layout, resize, widget

I have multiple widgets inside of a main window. Each widget and the main window all exist in layouts. In the case where there are two widgets next two each other is there a way to have one expand before the other expands/shrinks? I need both widgets to be expandable, but one is more important than the other. So, when the widgets shrink I need the widget on the left to shrink before the widget on the right shrinks.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved by setting a non-zero stretch on the widgets, and ensuring that they report proper maximum sizes. The stretch on the more important widget can be, say, 10x that of the less important widget. That way, the less important widget will grow very little unless the more important one is at full width.

Comment: This worked very well. The only thing I would add is if anyone is trying to do this with multiple widgets adjusting the stretch as above still works. Also if you want the widget on the far most left to stretch first, and the second widget to adjust next, and the last widget to expand last this can be done by setting the stretches to varying amounts say 10, 5, 1. The second widget will expand at the same time the first one does, but by considerably less until the first widget is at its max.

Comment: Additionally if you are using splitters as a layout instead of a regular horizontal or vertical layout adjusting the size via the splitter once the window is running will override the previously set stretch functions. If I find a fix for this I will add it here.